# Storing precedence of operations in database? Patterns?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a need to store a list of operations and their precedence or order in the database.
I am unsure whether to store operations with the highest precedence as ZERO or otherwise.
In other words, 
should the order of operations in precedence be stored in the database as :

```
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6'
```

OR

```
'6 5 4 3 2 1 0'
```

**TABLE DATA STRUCTURE:**

```
[operationName, precedence]
```

Also, a user can re-order them etc from the UI(a WPF app) in a list and hit "Save", in which case I will need to update them. He can also create a new operation and insert it into the list in the UI and hit SAVE ... which should also store the operations in the database according to the order in the UI.

**EDIT:**
Other things are they can even remove or delete them from the UI which needs to be updated to the database as well.
Are there any best practices or patterns surrounding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. Looks like you have a list of items that you need to save. You also need to sort the items by a user-defined order. A user can change order of items, can remove items etc. You want this to be persisted to a database.

Suppose you have a table in a database that stores your items. Just now there is nothing to store a user-defined order. What you need to add is a single property to the type (and a single column to the relation database's table) to reflect an order.

```
id | operation_name | user_order
--------------------------------
```

So when user reorders items, you save all of them back to the database, or alternatively execute an UPDATE statement and update the `user_order` column.

Basically, this is what you have just now. When you query your data, you can use this SQL

```
Select ...
From ...
Order by user_order
```

or the same in LINQ

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an audit trailing facility. If those sequences represent some dates then Event sourcing by Martin Fowler could show you some patterns:
[Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)